Select anidados o dependientes
Estoy haciendo una serie de select anidados de tres niveles, Paises / Provincias o Estados / Localidades.  Necesito dar el alta de una localidad, primero elijo el pais, luego debo elejir la provincia y finalmente escribo la localidad. Por ejemplo, al elegir Argentina, me debe trear Buenos Aires, Córdoba, etc.  Si elijo España, me debe treaer Barcelona, Valencia, etc. Finalmente al final tengo el input text para escribir la locallidad.
Lo estoy haciendo con PHP, MySQL y JS, esto es lo que hice hasta el momento:
En la carga de Localidades:
    <?php 
    include 'conexion.php';

    error_reporting(0);
    

    if  ( ( isset($_POST['Alta'])) ) {

        //Carga de datos
        //extract($_POST);
        $localidad = $_POST['localidad'];
        $provincia = $_POST["provincia"];
        $id_pais = $_POST["id_pais"];

        $sql="INSERT INTO localidades (localidad, provincia, id_pais) VALUES ('$localidad', '$provincia', '$id_pais')";
        $result=mysqli_query($conexion, $sql); 
        
   }
?>



<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Altas de Provincias</title>
    </head>

<body>  


    <form action="localidades_altas.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="localidades_altas">

        <?php
            $paises = 'SELECT * FROM paises ORDER BY pais';
            $id_pais = $conexion->query($paises);
        ?>
        <label for="pais">Elija el país:</label><br>
        <select name="id_pais" id="id_pais">
        <?php
          if ($id_pais->num_rows > 0) {
            // Mostrar los datos en el combo desplegable
            while($rowpais = $id_pais->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo '<option value="' . $rowpais["id"] . '">' . $rowpais["pais"] . ' </option>';
            }
        } else {
            echo '<option value="">No hay opciones disponibles</option>';
        } ?>
        </select><br><br>

            <label for="provincia">Elija la Provincia / Estado:</label><br>
            <select name="provincia" id="provincia">
                <option value="">Seleccionar</option>
            </select><br><br>

            <label for="localidad">Localidad:</label><br>
            <input name="localidad" id="localidad" type="text" placeholder="Ingrese un paísla localidad" required><br><br>


        <input type="submit" name="Alta" value="Guardar Localidad">

    </form>

    <script src="paisCiudadMuni.js"></script>

    <br><br><br>
    <?php 
        include "menu.php";
    ?>

El archivo JS está preparado para luego hacer una view de Paises, Provincias y Localidades al momento de tener que usarlo para otras cuestiones, como por ejemplo dar de alta un cliente y grabar su dirección postal.  El archivo es:
const cbxPais = document.getElementById('pais')
cbxPais.addEventListener("change", getProvincias)

const cbxProvincias = document.getElementById('provincia')
cbxProvincias.addEventListener("change", getLocalidades)

const cbxLocalidad = document.getElementById('localidad')

function fetchAndSetData(url, formData, targetElement) {
    return fetch(url, {
        method: "POST",
        body: formData,
        mode: 'cors'
    })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            targetElement.innerHTML = data;
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function getProvincias() {
    let pais = cbxPais.value;
    let url = 'getProvincias.php';
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_pais', pais);

    fetchAndSetData(url, formData, cbxProvincias)
        .then(() => {
            cbxLocalidad.innerHTML = ''
            let defaultOption = document.createElement('option');
            defaultOption.value = 0;
            defaultOption.innerHTML = "Seleccionar";
            cbxLocalidad.appendChild(defaultOption);
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

function getLocalidades() {
    let provincia = cbxProvincias.value;
    let url = 'getLocalidades.php';
    let formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id_provincia', provincia);

    fetchAndSetData(url, formData, cbxLocalidad)
        .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

getProvincias.php Para la carga de provincias:
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
//error_reporting(0);


$idPais = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['id_pais']);

$sql = $mysqli->query("SELECT id, provincia FROM provincias WHERE id_pais=$idPais");

$respuesta = "<option value='0'>Seleccionar</option>";

while ($row = $sql->fetch_assoc()) {
    $respuesta .= "<option value='" . $row['id'] . "'>" . $row['pais'] . "</option>";
}

echo json_encode($respuesta, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

La cuestión es que no funciona, elijo el país y no me trae las provincias.  No veo donde está el error.

¿Verificaste que la respuesta a la solicitud ajax a getProvincias.php devuelva algo? Proba hacer un console.log(data) justo antes de targetElement.innerHTML = data;

Has publicado una gran cantidad de código. Esto funciona mejor cuando preparas un [mcve] con el que quien quiera responderte pueda reproducir el problema (completo), contenga solo el código esencial para reproducirlo (mínimo) y así tenga un punto de partida para una posible respuesta. Eso aumentaría tus probabilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Encontrarás más información en [ask]. Un saludo.

Gracias Marcos, lo hice y no trae nada.

Prueba a quitar esto a tu formulario enctype="multipart/form-data", pues dicha declaración se pone cuando vas a mandar archivos junto con los datos y no es el caso aquí. Por otra parte, en algunos casos los datos que pasas por Fetch no se encuentran en $_POST, sino que van al flujo de entrada (ver aquí). Si es el caso, puedes obtenerlos con algo como $post=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input')); Haciendo eso, tendrás en $post lo que debería haber $_POST.
